# Main div isn't expanding vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I can't solve. I want my main div to expand vertically when its child div is filled with content, but couldn't make it. When I add lorem text to the left div, it expands if the text contains more than its original width, but the main div isn't expanding. How can I solve that problem?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#main{
  background-color:#ff8f79;
  width:900px;
  min-height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

#left{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  min-height:300px;
  float:left;
  background-color:blue;
}
#middle{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
}
#right{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
  background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3eu1k2fa/

Comment: You need to clear the float. Two methods 1. Clearfix: `#main:after { content: ' '; display: block; clear: both }` OR 2. `#main { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Thank you! I noted the solutions and will use in the future.

Comment: This has been covered a lot - [Here is an overview of 3 methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/) :) (only use the first method in that article if you have to support old browsers like IE6)

Answer (score -1):

add this to css

```
#left, #middle, #right {
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

keeps all the text within each individual box and they expand and also expand the main